# trying to get a orderby working on complex query

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

I cannot figure out where/how to put a orderby in this query.
I am needing the query ordered by the field branch (which is from Driver_Detail.assigned_area_name.

I have tried it multiple places and ways but it just gets ignored.

```
var stopsList = (from s in context.Mobile_Stops
                             join d in context.Driver_Detail on s.driver_number equals d.driver_number
                             where EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(s.requested_delivery_dateTime) == dateToUse.Date
                             group new { s, d } by new { s.driver_number } into g 
                             select new DriverDaySummary
                             {
                                 driver_Number = g.FirstOrDefault().d.driver_number,// d.driver_number,
                                 driver_Name = g.FirstOrDefault().d.first_name,
                                 branch = g.FirstOrDefault().d.assigned_area_name,
                                 Total_Stop_Count = g.ToList().Select(x => x.s).Count(),
                                 Delivered_Stops = g.ToList().Select(x => x.s).Where(x => x.status == 30).Count(),
                                 Exceptoined_Stops = g.ToList().Select(x => x.s).Where(x => x.status == 40).Count(),
                                 Open_Stops = (g.ToList().Select(x => x.s).Count() - (g.ToList().Select(x => x.s).Where(x => x.status == 30).Count() + g.ToList().Select(x => x.s).Where(x => x.status == 40).Count())),
                                 
                             }).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: jus order by `branch` as ordering by `assigned_area_name` is not possible here as you ar grouping by `driver_number ` and take first `assigned_area_name` you can add `OrderBy` right after `Distinct` ..

Comment: I have not been able to do that, I tried multiple ways.
I can't get the syntax correct:
  }).Distinct().OrderBy().ToList();

Comment: `OrderBy(dds=>dds.branch)`

Comment: thanks Selvin -- what was I thinking!?  Or not thinking...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just order by `branch` as ordering by `assigned_area_name` is not possible here as you are grouping by `driver_number`  and take first `assigned_area_name` you can add `OrderBy` right after `Distinct`.

<sub>The answer was provided by Selvin in the comments.</sub>